# If someone has a question here (meta) referring one of my posts can I be informed about it

Tags: discussion, feature-request

If someone has a question here (meta) referring one of my posts can I be informed about it while I don't visit meta regularly?

Comment: People usually leave comments on a post that is being discussed on meta.

Comment: @MiloBrandt My experience is that "usually" is too optimistic here. (Furthermore, users commenting on, and answering to, such posts, often do not feel the need to add such comments themselves.)

Comment: @Did perhaps we need to make a notification for when a stack exchange post is linked within stack exchange.